# Can you undo or revert a single line/block in TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm new to TFS and I can't figure out a way to undo a single line/ block. All I see is the option to undo the whole file.

Comment: Is something preventing you from just making a one-line edit and checking it in?

Comment: Say I made a couple changes to the file and then decided to discard some of the changes but keep the rest. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this at a more granular level than a changeset. For the scenario that you described you should do as Andrew suggested and instead just make the changes that you want and checkin.